# ajaxStop/Start not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am building a Wikipedia viewer, I have this in my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {         

    $(document).on('click', '#search_button', function() {          
      addWikiResults();          
    });

    $(document).keypress(function(enter) {
      if(enter.which == 13)
        addWikiResults();          
    });


    $(document).ajaxStop(function() { 
      alert('ajax stop now working');         
    });

  });
```

ajaxStop would not fire at all as well as ajaxStart. Everything works except that part. Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/nuclearmachine/pen/xdXXKv?editors=1000
specifically `line 130`

Comment: Please do search properly before posting a question same question asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730526/jquery-global-and-local-ajax-events-are-not-firing here

Comment: sorry, did not know what to google since googling "ajaxStop" yielded thousands of results but not the one I have. I mean, my code seems correct, console has no error numbers etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global events are never fired for cross-domain script or JSONP requests, regardless of the value of global.

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/